# How to implement Factory pattern with multiple parameters and each parameters are interface

Tags: design-patterns, factory, optional-parameters

I am a little bit confused on Factory Method with multiple parameters in which all parameters can change from GUI by user as seen below picture.

[image: GUI Screen parameter selection]

For each combobox item I have an interface and concrete implementations.

I have a SignalProcessor class which gets parameters as this 3 interfaces as below:

```
public interface ISignalProcessor
{
    double[] Process(double[] data);
}

 public class SignalProcessor : ISignalProcessor
{
    private IFft _fft;

    private IWindowing _windowing;

    private IInverseSpectrum _inverseSpectrum;

    private IDecimation _decimation;

    public SignalProcessor(IWindowing windowing, IFft fft,  IInverseSpectrum inverseSpectrum, IDecimation decimation)
    {
        _windowing = windowing;
        _fft = fft;
        _inverseSpectrum = inverseSpectrum;
        _decimation = decimation;
    }

    public double[] Process(double[] data)
    {
        var windowingResult = _windowing.Calculate(data);
        var fftResult = _fft.Calculate(windowingResult);
        var inverseSpectrumResult = _inverseSpectrum.Calculate(fftResult);
        return _decimation.Calculate(inverseSpectrumResult);
    }
}
```

I decided to produce and use concrete classes according to the selected combobox values so the following factory class created.

```
public static class FactorySP
{
    public static ISignalProcessor Create(string windowingType, int fftSize, bool isInverse, string decimationType)
    {
        return new SignalProcessor(CreateWindowing(windowingType), CreateFft(fftSize), CreateInverseSpectrum(isInverse), CreateDecimation(decimationType));
    }

    private static IWindowing CreateWindowing(string windowingType)
    {
        switch (windowingType)
        {
            case "Triangular":
                return new Triangular();
            case "Rectangular":
                return new Rectangular();
            case "Hanning":
                return new Hanning();
        }
    }

    private static IFft CreateFft(int fftSize)
    {
        switch (fftSize)
        {
            case 128:
                return new Fft128();
            case 256:
                return new Fft256();
            case 512:
                return new Fft512();
            default:
                return new FftNull();
        }
    }
    private static IInverseSpectrum CreateInverseSpectrum(bool isInverse)
    {
        if (isInverse)
            return new InverseSpectrumTrue();

        return new InverseSpectrumFalse();
    }

    private static IDecimation CreateDecimation(string decimationType)
    {
        if (decimationType == "RealTimeDecimation")
            return new RealTimeDecimation();

        return new SweepDecimation();
    }
}
```

Then used as follows:

```
_signalProcessor = FactorySP.Create(WindowingType, FftSize, InverseSpectrum, DecimationType);
result = _signalProcessor.Process(Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(a => (double)a).ToArray());
```

Is there a better way to get what I want than that? I feel there is something missing in the method I use :)
I know Factory method is not like that but otherwise I have to create all combinations and permutations of overload of factory classes.

Please help me to improve class implementation.

Best Regars,
Hakan

Comment: If this is working code you're looking to improve, the question is more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is Abstract Factory Design pattern.

Also you can checkout the Builder Design Pattern, when there are more parameters required to create an object.

Comment: Thank you that is what I am looking for.